# Bootstrap 4 Modal and jquery click event

Tags: jquery, onclick, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

everyone , I have an image inside a table cell when I click on that image a bootstrap 4 Modal is opened , I wanted to add click event to that image using JQuery but it doesn't work , Does adding a bootstrap Modal event to an element disables its Click event ????

this is the HTML code:

```
<span class="col-lg-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModal">
              <img id="myImg" class="img-responsive" src="/Content/uploads/done.png" style="cursor:pointer;"  alt="@item.OpportunityID"/>
            </span>
```

And the jquery code for testing is simple :

```
 $("#myImg").click(function () {
    alert("Clicked");

  });
```

Comment: try to trigger the jquery function

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Please can you explain more ?? dinesh

Comment: I Updated my question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably an issue with it being created dynamically. If you hook onto an element that's already on the page then it should work.

Change your click function to:

```
$('body').on('click', '#myImg', function () {
   alert('Clicked');
});
```

Comment: Thank you it worked Now. :) I will mark your answer as correct soon as the website allow me to.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it does not but what kind of click event are you trying to trigger in addition to the modal popping up? You could try to add a simple console.log("working") to see if the click event is really not fired.

Comment: I tried  a simple $("#id").click(function(){console.log("CLICKED")}); but it doesnt work.